# Replace z:row with zrow

Tags: 2010

Got the following xmlfile:

```
<xml>
...
<rs:data>
<z:row title .../>
...
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Now i want to replace rs:data with rsdata and z:row title..../> with zrow title..../>

The reason is I'm converting the xmlfile into an JSON Object and I want to access the values of the object.

```
object.rsdata.zrow.title;
```

I get started by using this:

```
var replacedxml = $.parseXML( xmlfile );
$(replacedxml).find("z\\:row, row").first().replaceWith('zrow');
```

Any help is appreciated.

====================================

Using: Sharepoint 2010 & jQuery

Comment: Take a look at JXON.

Comment: If you ask for JSON in your AJAX request, it should return JSON and you don't have to anything out of the ordinary. What does your get request look like?

Comment: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192010/sharepoint-2010-all-items-from-a-list-saving-in-an-array-and-looking-up-fo) here's the code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REST api and retrieve results in JSON format. See example below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var listName = "Announcements";

    var call = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var items = data.d.results;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var itemId = items[i].Id;
            var itemTitle = items[i].Title;
            window.console && console.log('ID:' + itemId);
            window.console && console.log('Title: ' + itemTitle);
            window.console && console.log('\n');
        }
    });

    call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error retrieving list items: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
});
```